# JS Web Worker and SP.JS - Type is not defined

Tags: javascript, html5

I'm experimenting with using CSOM and Web Workers as many of my users use Chrome and FireFox. Currently I am importing SP.js and SP.Core.js

```
importScripts("../SP.js", "../SP.Core.js");
```

What other scripts do I need to import? Currently I am getting the error

> Type is not defined.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a reference to `/_Layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js` you no longer get the Type is not defined error. The problem then becomes that `Type` is defined as inheriting from `window`.

> **[Type Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397723%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**
>
> > Provides a typing and type-reflection system for ECMAScript (JavaScript) object-oriented programming functionality.
> >
> > **Namespace:** None. The Type methods are global and not part of a
> >     namespace.
> >
> > **Inherits:** window.

Of course, a Web Worker does not have access to the `window` object. So it appears that it is not possible to use the CSOM with a Web Worker.

[Window, Self, and Web Workers](http://catchvar.com/window-self-and-web-workers)