# SP.js file not loaded in a simple JSOM example

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model, csom

I am creating a simple example that demonstrates  client object model using javascript. 
I have ceated a simple JS file in Visual Studio and an aspx page using the SharePoint Designer.

I have used the following command in  my aspx page to include the sp.js and sp.runtime.js files but no success and so I get an error which says "ReferenceError: Type is not defined" when I run the page. the command that is used to include the sp.js is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/sp.js"></script>
```

and the code in my js file which I created using Visual Studio is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
 retrieveListItems();

});
```

I am working on SharePoint 2013 enterprise edition and I have not used custom master page.

I am not able to figure out what is issue.  Comment ASAP.

Comment: Please confirm if this is SharePoint online? Are you using a custom master page? The sp.js reference you added is it inside the `AdditionalPageHead` placeholder?

Comment: Ok how about the 3rd question.

Comment: Please try that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19583/discussion-between-amal-hashim-and-mancy-desaee).

Comment: For some reason Chat page is not allowing me to login.. Ok can you please open the aspx page in SharePoint designer.. then search for AdditionalPageHead..

Comment: No, it isn't there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add javascript to sharepoint 2013](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114966/add-javascript-to-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used include all the requires javascripts as per the below sequence and there by I was able to include the SP.js.

```
<script src="/_layouts/1033/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have referred [this](http://allthatjs.com/2012/04/03/using-sharepoint-csom-in-html5-apps/) link.

The most important of all is that one should include jquery.min.js and not jquery.js. This is small point which would create havoc in your life.

Comment: So was your problem in the end that your reference to jquery was incorrect?

Answer (score 12):

Try adding following references to the additional page head of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
```

Then try using following script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
}); 

function retrieveListItems() {
    alert('Libraries Loaded');
}
```

Comment: Can you create a page using SharePoint UI instead of Designer?

Comment: In my case it worked just using jQuery(document).ready(function() { SP.SOD.executeFunc(…) }); because Sharepoint was loading sp.js after my script

Answer (score 4):

It could be you're calling retrieveListItems before SP.js has been fully loaded, in which case try:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);
```

Comment: I have tried this but it gives Type not defined error for SP.js.

Comment: Are you sure sp.js is actually in the _layouts folder? Try deploying it to a different location, like SiteAssets

Comment: Yes, I have checked that.

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to "/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" and you no longer get the Type is not defined error. I got the answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50995/js-web-worker-and-sp-js-type-is-not-defined).

Comment: Sorry to say but even this does not work.

Comment: Try this...                                            <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>

Comment: It is the ditto that I have used. Do you have some other solutions for this mind boggling problem?

Comment: Can you please do something like below using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded()...                     var clientContext;


ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initialize,"SP.js");

function initialize() {

 this.clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

}

Comment: Unless the SP.js file is loaded none of the code you mentioned will execute.

Comment: I think the order matters while referencing the JS files.

1. ASP.NET Ajax library(MicrosoftAjax.js)

2. sp.runtime.js file

3. sp.js file

 Please go through below link which will be helpful.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/09/04/using-the-javascript-object-model-jsom-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx

Please go through the comments also of the article given in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have jQuery loaded, perhaps you can use the `$.getScript()` function to load `SP.js`:

```
var scriptbase = siteUrl + '/_layouts/15/';

$.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
    function() {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js', retrieveListItems);
    }
);
```

Info on `$.getScript()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

Comment: What does _spPageContextInfo stand for? I am getting an error in this.

Comment: It contains general info about the page.  You can just hard code the site url in place of that. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

always must use

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="sp.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

I lost 2 days fighting with this , i dont know why nut it doesnt works using script src

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same problem because i referred the wrong List Column Internal Name in oListItem.get_item('ListFieldName')

Answer (score -1):

I said this before in another question:

[Add javascript to sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/114966/add-javascript-to-sharepoint-2013/114991)

> you can reference scripts in the masterpage of this forma:
>
> ```
> <SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="custom.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
> ```
>
> [Referncing a java script inside my master page will not fire](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76350/referncing-a-java-script-inside-my-master-page-will-not-fire)

**NOTE: you can use `<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="custom.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />` in a aspx file. For using it with JS `SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems);`**

Comment: It is not custom master page.

Comment: no matter you can use `<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="custom.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />` in a aspx file

Comment: The file is already loaded, the problem is `SP.JS`, which is already loaded via a ScriptLink. Read the other answers and the comments, you'll see that script on demand does not work.

Comment: and you used the command `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push` [WHAT DO I THINK? I'LL TELL YOU WHAT I THINK...
_SPBODYONLOADFUNCTIONNAMES IN SHAREPOINT VS. JQUERY’S DOCUMENT READY](http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/)