# Angular and SharePoint: missing references?

Tags: sharepoint-hosted-app, angularjs

Assume: I am new to Angular, still don't know what I am doing.

I am trying to create a SharePoint-hosted app that will pull some data from lists deployed with that app. I don't want to use Default.aspx page, but index.html with some Bootstrap.
[Andrew Connel's tutorial on Pluralsight](https://app.pluralsight.com/player?course=building-sharepoint-apps-spa-angularjs&author=andrew-connell&name=building-sharepoint-apps-spa-angularjs-m2-setup&clip=6&mode=live) is giving me some errors, all SharePoint code stops executing the moment I use .html. Probably I am doing something wrong.

[This tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/use-angularjs-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-illustrated/) (simplest one I've found) works perfect with Default.aspx :

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>


<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    Page Title
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">

    <div>
        <p id="message">
            <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
            initializing...
        </p>
    </div>
<div ng-app="employeesApp"> Displaying Employee data  
   <div ng-controller="EmployeesController">  
      <table><tr ng-repeat="emp in employees"> <td> {{ emp.title }} </td></tr></table>  
   </div>  
</div> 

</asp:Content>
```

App.js file:

```
'use strict';  
var hostweburl;  
var appweburl;  

var employeesApp = angular.module('employeesApp', []);  
employeesApp.controller('EmployeesController',  
    function($scope, $http) {  
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent($.getUrlVar("SPHostUrl"));  
        appweburl = decodeURIComponent($.getUrlVar("SPAppWebUrl"));  
        $scope.employees = [];  
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";  
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",  
            function() {  
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",  
                    function() {  
                        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", function() {  
                            var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);  
                            var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);  
                            context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);  
                            var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);  
                            var web = appContextSite.get_web();  
                            context.load(web);  

                            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Employee");  
                            var camlQuery = SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();  
                            this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);  
                            context.load(this.listItems);  

                            context.executeQueryAsync(  
                                Function.createDelegate(this, function() {  
                                    var ListEnumerator = this.listItems.getEnumerator();  
                                    while (ListEnumerator.moveNext()) {  
                                        var currentItem = ListEnumerator.get_current();  
                                        $scope.employees.push({  
                                            title: currentItem.get_item('Title')  
                                        });  


                                        $scope.$apply();  

                                    }  
                                }),  
                                Function.createDelegate(this, function(sender, args) {  
                                    alert('exception occured');  
                                })  
                            );  

                        });  
                    }  
                );  
            }  
        );  
    }  
);  
jQuery.extend({  
    getUrlVars: function() {  
        var vars = [],  
            hash;  
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');  
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {  
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');  
            vars.push(hash[0]);  
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];  
        }  
        return vars;  
    },  
    getUrlVar: function(name) {  
        return jQuery.getUrlVars()[name];  
    }  
});
```

Result (correct):
[image]

So i figured I will take all the references and make an html file based on aspx. It should work, right? It doesn't.

Default1.html file:

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>

</head>

    <div>
        <p id="message">
            <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
            initializing...
        </p>
    </div>
<div ng-app="employeesApp"> Displaying Employee data  
   <div ng-controller="EmployeesController">  
      <table><tr ng-repeat="emp in employees"> <td> {{ emp.title }} </td></tr></table>  
   </div>  
</div>
```

App.js remains the same. The results:

[image]

The console log:
[image]
**Question:** Why the employees did not show when Default1.html page was used? Is it a reference, a SharePoint library?
What is missing from .html file and how can I fix it?

Comment: probably the references are not loaded in time; try to use SP.SOD.executeFunc as in this post: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125580/sp-js-file-not-loaded-in-a-simple-jsom-example

Comment: why do they load with .aspx page?

Comment: because aspx page is managed by server and the loading sequence can be different

Comment: Eventually I used this and set the context in a separate function: $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.Runtime.js',
        function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js',
                function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', setSPContext); }
            );
        }
    );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By renaming it to .html, SharePoint doesn't know how to parse the <% %> tags (which are ASP.NET). They are rendered on the server before being sent to the client.

The errors you see in the browser simply mean they don't understand the server-based tags.

If you remove the first two comment lines <% ... %>, the page should no longer display those errors.

Update:

SharePoint App services makes your life easier by including appropriate references etc, so unless you NEED to make it a plain HTML file, let SharePoint do the hard work of managing references, and focus on building the app. :)